# upload documents to case feed in batch

Tags: case, feeditem

I have several documents that need to be upload as case feed items to their cases. Since I have 1000 such documents I would like to know if there is a way I can automate this task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload using data loader. But it requires keeping data in specific format in local folders. Check below link,
http://www.shellblack.com/administration/import-attachments-using-the-data-loader/